# Why is Symfony2 parsing the entire Forms Collection - Performance issue

Tags: php, forms, performance, symfony

I have a Forms Collection in my Symfony2.3 project.

From time to time, I can have up to 200 forms in my collection.

Then, in order to speed up things, I am only submitting some of those 200 forms (ex: 1).

I am then reaching the POST action in my controller.

Te problem is that when doing

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

It takes long time to finish, I think that there, I am getting through all those objects.

Is there a possibility to parse only the submitted forms from the collection?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use the form builder collection to render 200 forms then Symfony will expect to get back 200 forms in return.

Comment: There is no possibility not to return all the 200 forms?

Comment: Well.  First off, when using a collection you really are just returning one form with 200 parts.  Make sure you understand that.  If we assume that each sub form deals with one entity then I suppose you could have your controller check the response for a post, manually extract the id's of the posted entities and then use them as your collection.  Never tried it.  I do question the value of having 200 forms.  I think I would try an ajax based solution.

Comment: I should also point out the 200 entities is really not that many unless they have complex tree structures. Might want to make sure that your performance issues are not something else.  I assume you tried with 2 then 20 then 60 etc.

Comment: Hi @Cerad, yes, I tryed with 10, 20, 50, 200... The speed is more and more slow. I started working on your 1st proposed solution yesterday, parsing the post manually and do only some of the subforms. I will let you know how it works. By the way, it is strange that Symfony still receave all the 200 subforms and I am deleting them from the html form !!!

Comment: It's not that symfony is receiving the 200 forms.  It's that symfony first generates the 200 forms and then maps the request data on them.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I finished by parsing the response manually and do the data insertion manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparwently, when using collection of forms, symfony will try to parse all those forms ant create the objects.

What I did to avoid that is: Instead f using `$form->handleRequest($request);`, I parsed manually the POST array, and checked if the object was edited or not. If edited, do something, if not, continue.

This way, I reduced the parsing time of 200 objects from 45 to 2 sec.